# Parsing using awk or sed in Unix

Tags: parsing, unix, shell, sed, awk

I have multiple files with hundreds of thousands of records in following format:

`2010/08/10 10:07:52|TrainZoom|1393|38797|MyCustomerAPI->,mask = ZPTA,TransId = 1281460071578,testing :-> ,    capture -> : , IMDB = 9113290830,        equipmentName = GMT,        technologyName = RMS,,,)|`

There are fields separated by pipes and inside a field (last) there are many other fields separated by commas. What I want to do is to store all these values in database. For the above example my DB fields would be date-time, process-name, thread-id, sequence-num, API name, transId, imdb, equipmentName, technologyName.
API Name is not in a fixed format but I can assume that its a fixed length.

Please let me know if I can do this in Unix using awk or sed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|/insert into table set date-time=\1, process-name=\2, thread-id=\3, sequence-num=\4, /' -e 's/,[^=]*,/,/g' -e 's/ \([,=]\)/\1/g' -e 's/\([,=]\) /\1/g' -e 's/\([^,]*\)=\([^,]*\),/\1="\2",/g' -e 's/"[^"]*$/";/' | mysql dbname
```

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm. How much time it took for you to format this command? You are great. Can you also please tell me if I want to generate an statement like this `insert into mytab (date_time,thread_id,seq_num, field1, field2) values ('2010/02/09',201,1001,'Test','Test')` how can modify above command or use another command to format the output of above. Thanks.

Comment: +1 since you said "just for fun".  Otherwise, I would have downvoted such an evil response :-)

Comment: This is really nice, helped me learn a little about sed. What does the following mean though: 's/\\([,=]\\) /\1/g'

Comment: But still, a useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do at least the parsing in awk,

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{q="\047"}
{
 printf "insert into table values("
 printf q $1 q","q $2,","
 # fill up the rest yourself
}
' file
```

the above produces a bunch of insert statements. You can either pipe them to your database client, or save them to a .sql file, then use the database client to execute it.

Comment: You can then use the database command line tools to do an insert. E.g. For mySQL it would be "mysql -u username -p database_name < insertScript.sql"

Answer (score 1):

I would use perl or python to do the job as they provide DB connectors for different flavor of DBs. I don't see what you want awk or sed to do, as they are "text to text transformers".

You should complete your question to clarify your goal (text => sql script? for example) and target DB if you want some sample code.

Comment: most (if not all) database also provide database clients that can execute sql scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the parsing, at least, directly in bash. I'm not sure what you want to *do* with the values, but this script parses each line and displays the individual fields:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='|' read dateTime processName threadId sequenceNum other; do
    IFS=',' read apiName mask transId testing capture imdb equipmentName technologyName other <<< "$other"

    echo "date-time:       $dateTime"
    echo "process-name:    $processName"
    echo "thread-id:       $threadId"
    echo "sequence-num:    $sequenceNum"
    echo "api-name:        $apiName"
    echo "trans-id:        $transId"
    echo "imdb:            $imdb"
    echo "equipment-name:  $equipmentName"
    echo "technology-name: $technologyName"
done
```