# What does \1 in sed do?

Tags: sed

I found this question really relevant to what I wanted: [Parsing using awk or sed in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633155/parsing-using-awk-or-sed-in-unix), however I can't figure out what the following does:

```
's/\([,=]\) /\1/g'
```

I know that g does a global substitution but really can't understand what's going on within the context of the question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | sed 's/\(ab\)c/\1/'
ababcabc
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | sed 's/\(ab\)c/\1/g'
ababab
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | sed 's/\(ab\)\(c\)/\1d\2/g'
abdcabdcabdc
```

In the first command, only the first match is affected. In the second command, every match is affected. In both cases, the `\1` refers to the characters captured by the escaped parentheses.

In the third command, two capture groups are specified. They are referred to by using `\1` and `\2`. Up to nine capture groups can be used.

In addition to the `g` (global) operator (or without it, the first match), you can specify a particular match:

```
$ echo 'aaaaaa' | sed 's/a/A/4'
aaaAaa
```

Comment: What is \\1 doing, is it extended regex?

Comment: Here is an example for \\1: `sed  -E -e "s/[^/]{10}(\\.[^\\.]+)?$/\\1/"`

Comment: @Timo: `\1` inserts the contents of the first capture group which is what matches between the first set of parentheses. I don't know whether you're asking in particular about the case with doubled backslashes, but it seems to work whether they are doubled or not. I wouldn't say that's a case of extended regex because it does the same thing even when you're using basic regex.

Comment: To be precise, in `s/foo/bar/`, only `foo` is a regular expression, and the rest is other `sed` syntax. Basically, `bar` is just a string, though some things like `&` and `\1` have a special meaning in that string.

Answer (score 30):

`\(...\)` would capture the characters specified inside of the parens and `\1` would be used to reference the first match, this is a part of regex.

Comment: Good answer.  I just wanted to add that this means the specific example cited removes a space following either a comma or equals sign, because the `\1` puts back whatever was matched between the parens, which didn't include the space.

Comment: So is the /g needed if you are only referencing the first match?

Comment: Note: it is not needed to espace parentheses with a backslash if you use extended regex with `sed -E`.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly The role of `/g` is unrelated to anything in the back reference. Without `/g`, `sed` will only substitute the first occurrence of the regex on each line; with `/g` you are saying, "if that succeeded, proceed from that point in the input string and replace the next one, too; repeat until you cannot find any more matches." From this exposition, it should be clear that `\1` will necessarily refer to a different part of the input string every time (because the search continues only from the point after the previous match).

Comment: @baptx To be precise, not only is it "not necessary"; the backslashes take on a different (and IMHO more logical) meaning with `-E`; then `\(` means "match one literal opening parenthesis" (and `(` is a grouping parenthesis which matches nothing, just organizes the regex).