# Regex to capture final subdirectory regardless of whether it's followed by a terminal slash character?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a set of directory path names that could look either like this:

```
foo/bar/baz
```

or like this, with an extra slash on the end:

```
foo/bar/baz/
```

Furthermore the directory path could be arbitrarily deep--it's not guaranteed to be only 3 levels as I have shown here; there might be more levels than that.

I'd like to write a regular expression to capture the right-most subdirectory name, regardless of which of the two forms is presented.

I can write a regular expression `'[^/]*$'` for grep which works correctly for the first case:

```
> grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
> echo "foo/bar/baz" | grep -o '[^/]*$'
baz
>
```

How can I extend this to incorporate the second case as well?  It seems like I'd need to capture 0 or more slashes on the right hand side (i.e., next to the "$"), but then throw them away, and match only stuff further to the left than that.  But I can't quite figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: See [`sed -E 's@.*/([^/]+).*@\1@'`](http://ideone.com/ffTEuD) (or with `-r` option instead of `-E`, depends on the OS). Or try `grep -oP '[^/]+(?=/?$)'`

Comment: Thank-you!  I hadn't encountered the \1 syntax in sed before, and I ended up having to [look it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609949/what-does-1-in-sed-do) in order to understand how your solution works.  The grep solution that you suggested also works, although on my system I had to install [pcregrep](http://www.pcre.org/) in order to obtain a version of grep that would support extended expressions.

Comment: Mac OSX `grep` does not support `P`. Do you want me to post the solution with `sed`? I still think anubhava's solution is the best as it will work in all  versions with `awk`.

Comment: Please don't feel obligated to post it if you don't want to spend the time.  However, I consider it a valid solution, so if you do post it, I would consider it my duty to upvote it.

Comment: See my answer added below.

Comment: Yes, I was somewhat indecisive about which of the two to accept.  I admit that I like the awk solution very much, however I felt the other solution looked the most similar to the way I had been trying to do it initially, and thus I felt a moral obligation to select that one as it seemed to hew most closely to what I considered the "spirit" of the original query.  BTW, I think you should relax your self-imposed requirements; novelty is also a good justification for posting, even if the solution is perhaps less general, or merely good but not the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an optional `/?` before the EOL anchor `$`

`/[^\/]+(?=\/?$)/`

https://regex101.com/r/mHzLx0/1

Explain

```
 [^/]+                # Not forward slash char's
 (?= /? $ )           # Lookahead, optional / then EOS
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closest to what I had in mind, although I couldn't figure out on my own how to construct the lookahead group correctly.  Also, note to others who may find this: the factory installed version of grep on my mac OS X operating system does not support the lookahead syntax; I had to download [pcregrep](http://www.pcre.org/) in order to get access to extended regular expressions so that it would work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> Furthermore the directory path could be arbitrarily deep--it's not guaranteed to be only 3 levels as I have shown here; there might be more levels than that.

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{sub(/\/$/, ""); print $NF}' <<< "foo/bar/baz"
baz

awk -F/ '{sub(/\/$/, ""); print $NF}' <<< "foo/bar/baz/"
baz

awk -F/ '{sub(/\/$/, ""); print $NF}' <<< "abc/xyz/foo/bar/baz/"
baz
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  Not what I was expecting (I thought you'd just add something extra to the simpler regex that I started with) but nevertheless this certainly gets the job done.  Thank-you.

Comment: With `BSH grep` you will need to pipe the result to `tr` or `sed` such as: `grep -oE '[^/]+/?$' <<< "abc/xyz/foo/bar/baz/" | tr -d '/'
baz`. However I find `awk` solution easier here.

Answer (score 1):

"Converting" my comment to an answer:

## Solution using `sed`

```
sed -E 's@.*/([^/]+).*@\1@'
```

The `-E` (or `-r`, depends on the OS) enables the POSIX ERE syntax.

**Pattern details**:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `/` - a `/` symbol
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible, up to the end of a line.

The `\1` in the replacement part copies back into the result the contents that are stored in Group 1 memory buffer.

## Solution with GNU `grep`

If you have access to a PCRE powered `grep` (GNU `grep`, for example) you may use

```
grep -oP '[^/]+(?=/?$)'
```

where `-o` option enables extraction of each match (rather than a line where a match was found) and `-P` forces `grep` to use the PCRE regex engine to parse the pattern. It enables the *lookaround* feature. Lookarounds are non-consuming patterns, i.e. the texts they match are not added to the match value and do not advance the regex index, thus, they are good for checking various conditions inside regex.

**Pattern details**:

- `[^/]+` - a negated bracket expression that matches any char but `/`, 1 or more times, up to
- `(?=/?$)` - an optional `/` (the `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences) at the end of the line (`$`).

And here is the [state-of-the-art PCRE regex Web testing site demo](https://regex101.com/r/oYDWZB/1).