# Capitalise a varying phrase in same position in Terminal

Tags: bash, perl, text, awk, sed

I have a number of `.py` files that contain a line like this:

```
self._cols = [self.foo.bar.relevant_string.str()]
```

I need to capitalise the `relevant_string`, to get this

```
self._cols = [self.foo.bar.RELEVANT_STRING.str()]
```

in all ~100 of them.

Is there a way to do this with bash/awk/perl? I tried something like this

```
perl  -pe 's/self.foo.bar./uc($&)/e' *.py
```

But it capitalised the captured area, not the part after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\K` after your pattern to omit it from the match and match the part you need to change the case of using `\w+` (that matches 1 or more letters, digits or underscores):

```
perl -i -pe 's/self\.schemata\.usage\.\K\w+/uc($&)/e' *.py
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YEaOcZ):

```
s="self._cols = [self.schemata.usage.relevant_string.str()]"
perl -pe 's/self\.schemata\.usage\.\K\w+/uc($&)/e' <<< "$s"
# => self._cols = [self.schemata.usage.RELEVANT_STRING.str()]
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been really helpful. One other thing - I think this just prints to the terminal, is there a way to change inplace?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Yes, use `-i` option

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
$ echo 'self._cols = [self.foo.bar.relevant_string.str()]' |
    sed -E 's/(self\.foo\.bar\.)([^.]+)/\1\U\2/'
self._cols = [self.foo.bar.RELEVANT_STRING.str()]
```

Comment: Thanks! Was going to ask about the `1` and `2`, but I think I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609949/what-does-1-in-sed-do) (leaving the link for posterity)

Answer (score 2):

One more Perl, using look-behind

```
$ echo "self._cols = [self.foo.bar.relevant_string.str()]" |
    perl -pe 's/(?<=self.foo.bar.)(\w+)/uc($1)/ge'
self._cols = [self.foo.bar.RELEVANT_STRING.str()]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/self\.foo\.bar\.[^.]*/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART+12) toupper(substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
self._cols = [self.foo.bar.RELEVANT_STRING.str()]
```

Answer (score 0):

use perl 5, or gnu sed

```
perl -i -pe 's/(self.foo.bar.)(\w+)/\1\U\2/g' *.py
```

identically just replace 'perl -i -pe' with

```
sed -i -E
```